# ADYEN : Unable to see adyen metadata block on my payment details page

Tags: payment, adyen

I am sending the metadata object with some fields on the payment apis and i can see the same on the API logs Request body
but when i open this payment under payment details page i am not able to see the same
also on the settlement details report it is coming up as blank

spoke to customer care they said i dont have access